# Pip creates build/ directories

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

I use virtualenv to create isolated environments for my Python projects. Then i install dependencies with pip - Python package manager. Sometimes i forget to do `source venv/bin/activate`, and then pip creates `build/` directories inside my projects. Why does pip create them? May i delete them, and if not, may i put them in my `.hgignore` file?

As far as i understand, pip stores source of downloaded packages there along a file called `pip-delete-this-directory.txt`. But when i delete it, everything still works, as the real code is being put into `venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`. Then what is `build/` really for?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The `build` directory is where a packages gets unpacked into and build from. When the package is installed successfully, pip removes the unpacked dir from `build`, unless you've removed `pip-delete-this-directory.txt`. As described in `pip-delete-this-directory.txt`:

```
This file is placed here by pip to indicate the source was put
here by pip.

Once this package is successfully installed this source code will be
deleted (unless you remove this file).
```

Thus its less important for runtime environment. You could ignore it safely.

Also, you could use `pip install -b customized_build_directory` to specify another directory as `build` base directory, for example `/tmp`

Furthermore, you could `pip install --no-download package_name` to rebuild the package w/o downloading it, if the previous installation of the package failed.

Comment: So why might I have a build directory, even when I did not remove the pip-delete-this-directory.txt? Is it an option that I can unset?

Comment: @Alex It's OK to point the directory to another more transient place such as `/tmp`, did you mean that?

Comment: Sure, pointing it at /tmp is fine. I'm just commenting that despite pip's claim, it often does NOT remove the build directory after a successful install.

Comment: The `-b` option really helps on systems where `/tmp` has `noexec` attribute.

Comment: `Once this package is successfully installed this source code will be deleted`... except that it wasn't.  Is it really supposed to be deleted automatically?  Why wasn't it for me?  I pip installed with `-e git+ssh://etc...`, and no other special options.