# Install python module on synology - pip error

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pip, synology

I'm trying to install additional python module on my Synology DS112J. I installed pip and now i'm trying to install modules. It works with the module "requests" but don't with matplotlib and numpy.

It says "Error : no more space" but my synology has something like 3To and more space :/

I got this logfile :

```
------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/local/bin/pip run on Tue Oct  7 23:00:40 2014
Downloading/unpacking matplotlib
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/
  URLs to search for versions for matplotlib:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/m/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.4.0-cp26-none-win32.whl#md5=774d62b98c9a7bcfcf29b65c0b3bb056 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/m/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.4.0-cp26-none-win_amd64.whl#md5=198652a75d184f4f6900f74fb9d68a7f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/m/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.4.0-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl#md5=19649b0bbb78ef3a2cce1e1c64cbb78f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/m/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.4.0-cp27-none-win32.whl#md5=bf8dfe71fd37d209d7287d4e0565f02b (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/m/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.4.0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl#md5=f3f581901736f547e3e1e4d8f2b0872a (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.2/m/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.4.0-cp32-none-win32.whl#md5=3e508b3e606cdf49f8301f5a513cafba (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.2/m/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.4.0-cp32-none-win_amd64.whl#md5=d41dae609c981068207b1a5ea93cb066 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.3/m/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.4.0-cp33-cp33m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl#md5=16d28bb4a986eb550a66e463f7b0494f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.3/m/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.4.0-cp33-none-win32.whl#md5=015470511cc3f7f39ae26b502a0c5ff6 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.3/m/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.4.0-cp33-none-win_amd64.whl#md5=324189994b669b6a877f22084db86044 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.4/m/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.4.0-cp34-cp34m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl#md5=9f3be17be6556edcae2abfb2137c3c90 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.4/m/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.4.0-cp34-none-win32.whl#md5=d4bb6a18cb529858ff05be03f958fc66 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.4/m/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.4.0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl#md5=84bba66e4aa7101005f7503708c186ac (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp27/m/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.3.1-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl#md5=ea9eb2cf47e4ca76395077c247644b2f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp33/m/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.3.1-cp33-cp33m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl#md5=c274d751c438b69b478cb617503c3231 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp34/m/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.3.1-cp34-cp34m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl#md5=2c5ed43ecbddb347ef5e59cbfd42b366 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/m/matplotlib/matplotlib-0.86.1.tar.gz#md5=d3727dc75c4c1cff0b0bae856b4e5ad8 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/), version: 0.86.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/m/matplotlib/matplotlib-0.86.2.tar.gz#md5=9bb3f2b70a26e131c6b10743e8c49fc5 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/), version: 0.86.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/m/matplotlib/matplotlib-0.86.tar.gz#md5=4770cbcddabcbab72d48fbb237ed5d8c (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/), version: 0.86
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/m/matplotlib/matplotlib-0.91.0.tar.gz#md5=059aa32556644760aef9cec9fb8fc3ac (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/), version: 0.91.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/m/matplotlib/matplotlib-0.91.1.tar.gz#md5=56a9344b077b5accbc4823be19f69dd6 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/), version: 0.91.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/m/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.0.1.tar.gz#md5=2196c0482d5b33dc8d33f67bbafc1323 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/), version: 1.0.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/m/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.1.0.tar.gz#md5=091a4d08c6f9fd7e5f7f63adc1abc351 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/), version: 1.1.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/m/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.1.1.tar.gz#md5=30ee59119599331bf1f3b6e838fee9a8 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/), version: 1.1.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/m/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.3.1.tar.gz#md5=789699851de28a543f3d244cf657ff68 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/), version: 1.3.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/m/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.4.0.tar.gz#md5=1daf7f2123d94745feac1a30b210940c (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/), version: 1.4.0
    Skipping link http://matplotlib.org (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/); not a file
    Skipping link http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/); not a file
    Skipping link http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/); unknown archive format: .php
    Skipping link http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706&package_id=82474 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/); unknown archive format: .php
    Skipping link http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.1.0/ (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/); unknown archive format: .0
    Skipping link http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.1.1/ (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/); unknown archive format: .1
    Skipping https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/matplotlib/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.2.0/matplotlib-1.2.0.tar.gz (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) because it is externally hosted.
    Skipping https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/matplotlib/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.2.1/matplotlib-1.2.1.tar.gz (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) because it is externally hosted.
    Skipping https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/matplotlib/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.3.0/matplotlib-1.3.0.tar.gz (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) because it is externally hosted.
    Skipping https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/matplotlib/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.3.1/matplotlib-1.3.1.tar.gz (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) because it is externally hosted.
    Skipping https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/matplotlib/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.4.0/matplotlib-1.4.0.tar.gz (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) because it is externally hosted.
    Skipping link https://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706&package_id=278194 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/); unknown archive format: .php
    Skipping link https://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706&package_id=82474 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/); unknown archive format: .php
    Skipping link https://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-0.99.1/ (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/); unknown archive format: .1
    Skipping link https://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-0.99.3/ (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/); unknown archive format: .3
    Skipping link https://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.0 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/); unknown archive format: .0
    Skipping link https://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.0.1/ (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/); unknown archive format: .1
    Skipping https://svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/matplotlib/trunk/matplotlib#egg=matplotlib-dev (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) because it is externally hosted.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.org (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.org (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.org (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.org (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.org (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706&package_id=82474 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706&package_id=82474 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706&package_id=82474 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706&package_id=82474 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706&package_id=82474 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706&package_id=82474 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706&package_id=82474 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706&package_id=82474 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.1.0/ (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.1.1/ (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/matplotlib/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.2.0/matplotlib-1.2.0.tar.gz (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/matplotlib/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.2.1/matplotlib-1.2.1.tar.gz (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/matplotlib/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.3.0/matplotlib-1.3.0.tar.gz (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/matplotlib/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.3.1/matplotlib-1.3.1.tar.gz (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/matplotlib/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.4.0/matplotlib-1.4.0.tar.gz (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching https://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706&package_id=278194 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching https://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706&package_id=278194 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching https://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706&package_id=82474 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching https://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706&package_id=82474 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching https://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-0.99.1/ (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching https://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-0.99.3/ (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching https://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.0 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Not searching https://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.0.1/ (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
  Using version 1.4.0 (newest of versions: 1.4.0, 1.3.1, 1.1.1, 1.1.0, 1.0.1, 0.91.1, 0.91.0, 0.86.2, 0.86.1, 0.86)
  Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/m/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.4.0.tar.gz#md5=1daf7f2123d94745feac1a30b210940c (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/)
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir /tmp/pip_build_root...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1197, in prepare_files
    do_download,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1375, in unpack_url
    self.session,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 582, in unpack_http_url
    unpack_file(temp_location, location, content_type, link)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/util.py", line 625, in unpack_file
    untar_file(filename, location)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/util.py", line 586, in untar_file
    shutil.copyfileobj(fp, destfp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 52, in copyfileobj
    fdst.write(buf)
IOError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

Can someone explain me what's wrong with the installation of the module ?

EDIT : I saw some post talking about the "tmp space". They say to do the df command. Here is the result :

```
DiskStation> df -h
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1                 2.3G    607.0M      1.6G  26% /
/tmp                     57.9M     49.1M      8.8M  85% /tmp
/dev/mapper/vol1-origin
                          1.8T     57.0G      1.7T   3% /volume1
/volume1/@optware         1.8T     57.0G      1.7T   3% /opt
```

So, apparently the tmp folder have only 57.9M, can I increase this size ?

Comment: you would have to  repartition the drive to expand  tmp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears from the log message:

```
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir /tmp/pip_build_root...
IOError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

DiskStation> df -h
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/tmp                     57.9M     49.1M      8.8M  85% /tmp
```

that pip is running out of space because it is using /tmp as the build directory.

You can use

```
pip install -b customized_build_directory
```

to [specify a different directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10618122/190597).

---

There are tools like [GParted](http://gparted.org/) which can resize partitions without re-partitioning, but it can take a long time to complete for a large hard drive. Moreover, if you have a backup drive (which is the only safe way to operate!) it is quicker to backup, repartition, and restore.

Comment: Thanks for the -b, I didn't knew it. 
For Gparted, it doesn't exist on synology I think (it's not Linux, it's busy box or something like that). 

I have no another problem >.< :
The required version of distribute (>=0.6.28) is not available.