# What is pip-delete-this-directory.txt? Can I delete this file?

Tags: python, pip, delete-file

If I install a pip package via:

```
pip install -e -e git+https://example.com/repos/foo#egg=foo
```

a file called `pip-delete-this-directory.txt` gets created.

Can I delete this file, or would doing that break something?

Where is the canonical reference/documentation for this file?

Comment: where is this directory created?

Comment: @PierredeBuyl I don't know. The directory was not created by me. I guess pip did it.

Comment: You observe that the file `pip-delete-this-directory.txt` is created by pip. I can only guess from my tests that this is in the cache of pip. If you read the file, it probably says that pip will delete package from the directory after successful installation. If you remove it, old downloads of packages will accumulate.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl thank you for your comment. Sorry for nitpicking. Is there are canonical reference which explains the reason why this file exists? I guess your guess is correct. But I am a scaredy cat, I don't like guesses.

Comment: Before guessing further, why do you use the "editable" mode (flag `-e`)? In that case, the files will still be used. I suppose it is the reason it is left there. Do you need "editable" mode for the package?

Comment: In short: if you were to install the package "regularly" (no `-e`), pip would delete the source package. As you use `-e`, you keep a copy of the package that is not under the python system path. To make itself aware that other source packages should still be deleted, pip leaves this file behind.

Comment: @guettli : this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617198/pip-creates-build-directories

Comment: @guettli : insert pip-delete-this-directory.txt in every build directory pip creates temporarily (it identifies pip created that), and always remove it if no
longer needed. https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/60

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a sample of a [pip-delete-this-directory.txt](http://trails.imlab.ucla.edu/build/pip-delete-this-directory.txt) which contains the following lines:

> This file is placed here by pip to indicate the source was put
>   here by pip.
>
> Once this package is successfully installed this source code will be
>   deleted (unless you remove this file).

And the upvoted response of this question: [Pip creates build/ directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617198/pip-creates-build-directories?answertab=votes#tab-top), reinforces my believe that nothing will get broken if you delete this file, but the source code of the module you installed will remain on your computer and take up space. If that is not a concern for you then you don't need to delete it!

Comment: Sorry, I was too late give you the bounty. I hope it is ok, that you only get the half. I can give a second bounty if it is important for you.

Comment: No problem mate, I am not a bounty hunter, only wanted to help! :D

Comment: Hey @guettli I was doing a pass through my answers, did you found this one helpful?

Comment: Yes, it as helpful.